# Forcing English as admin interface language on LinguaPlone sites

Tags: plone, linguaplone

We are hosting multilingual Plone sites. The default Plone behavior is to use the current content language for admin interface labels. We'd like to change this behavior so that admin interface language is always English, regardless of content.

This will make managing multilingual content easier if you have little or no target language skills.

If we can set this so that when you login as admin and are member of certain or have certain role, the behavior kicks in.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to override language when i18n translation machinery queries the string for *plone* or other i18n domain providing admin text strings.

Overriding request.LANGUAGE has side-effects which will make your site unusuable. E.g. folder listings won't work.

Here is a package which does what you want:

https://github.com/miohtama/silvuple

Answer (score 2):

You can register your own INegotiateLanguage multi-adapter from Products.PloneLanguageTool to allow for customisation. IIRC (it was a while ago I added that multi-adapter) you can just register it as an adapter on your own plone.browserlayer interface, though I'm not absolutely certain the browser layer gets applied early enough.

Answer (score 0):

we had the same requirement and solved it by adding a javascript for managers, replacing the the strings. not ideal because of the redundant vocabulary/dictionary, but worked fine for us.